# datagrid binding boolean in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have 3 columns . One with check box , One with text  column and one column with drop down.

I am binding the entire table itemsource to StepTaskViewInfo.CurrentStep.ProjectTasks.Items . StepTaskViewInfo is a variable in my VM and others are nested in it. This works fine .

Only thing that doesnt work is the IsReadOnly property of the FIRST Columns. Am assuming this is some issue because my items source is different and the read only property is different in terms of level of nesting from view model.

```
For grid :
Items Source = StepTaskViewInfo -> CurrentStep -> ProjectTasks- >Items 

For read only propety of each column(which doesnt work) :

IsReadOnly="{Binding StepTaskViewInfo.AreStepsTasksReadonly


StepTaskViewInfo  => AreStepsTasksReadonly



         <DataGrid RowHeaderWidth="0" x:Name ="TaskDataGrid"  Margin="20,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding StepTaskViewInfo.CurrentStep.ProjectTasks.Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                            CanUserSortColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" CanUserAddRows="False"  SelectionChanged="TaskRowSelectionChanged" 
                                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                                      Background="White" BorderThickness ="0"
                                      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" Height="240">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width ="60" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" Header="Selected" IsReadOnly="{Binding StepTaskViewInfo.AreStepsTasksReadonly,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }">
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <CheckBox  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                                           IsEnabled="{Binding IsTaskEnabled,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>



       //Column 2
                                    <DataGridTextColumn HeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" Header="Tasks" Width ="*" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True">
                                        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                                            </Style>
                                        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                        <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                                            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                                                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                                                <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="true" />
                                            </Style>
                                        </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                                    </DataGridTextColumn>




        //Column 3


                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn  HeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" Header="Status" Width ="130">
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate >
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="130">
                                                    <Label Content ="Status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin ="0,0,0,0"/>
                                                    <ComboBox Name ="DefaultStatusComboBox" ItemsSource="{StaticResource Status}" Width="86"  DropDownClosed="DefaultStatusComboBox_DropDownClosed"  />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Status, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height ="26" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsReadOnly ="{Binding StatusIsReadOnly}" 
                                                  IsEnabled ="{Binding IsSelected}"  ItemsSource="{StaticResource Status}"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>





view model:

public class StepTaskViewModel : INavigationAware, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {


 private readonly IProjectWorkflowService projectWorkflowService;
    private bool isVisible = true;
    private readonly IUserService userService;



        private string stageId;
        private StepTaskViewInfo stepTaskViewInfo;

        public StepTaskViewModel(IProjectWorkflowService projectWorkflowService, IUserService userService)
        {
            this.projectWorkflowService = projectWorkflowService;
            this.userService = userService;
            StepTaskViewInfo=new StepTaskViewInfo();
        }

        public StepTaskViewInfo StepTaskViewInfo
        {
            get { return stepTaskViewInfo; }
            set
            {
                stepTaskViewInfo = value; 

                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        // set current step - >load tasks - > set display names for each task --> set drop down source for current step


        public string StageId
        {
            get { return stageId; }
            set
            {
                stageId = value;
                StepTaskViewInfo.PeerReview.StageId = stageId;
                LoadData();
            }
        }




        #region navigation
        public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
        {
            StageId =(string) navigationContext.Parameters["StageId"] ;
            IsVisible = true;

        }

        public bool IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
        {
            if (!IsVisible)
                return;
            IsVisible = false;
        }

        public bool IsVisible
        {
            get { return isVisible; }
            set
            {
                isVisible = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "" )
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion

        // called when stage id changes
        public void LoadData()
        {

            var stepTaskViewInfo = projectWorkflowService.LoadProjectStepTaskInfo(StageId);

            if (StepTaskViewInfo.CurrentStep != null)
            {
                StepTaskViewInfo.CurrentStep.ProjectTasks.Items.Clear();
            }
            StepTaskViewInfo.AllTeamMembers = stepTaskViewInfo.AllTeamMembers;
            StepTaskViewInfo.ProjectSteps = stepTaskViewInfo.ProjectSteps;
            StepTaskViewInfo.PeerReview = stepTaskViewInfo.PeerReview;
            StepTaskViewInfo.AreStepsTasksReadonly = stepTaskViewInfo.AreStepsTasksReadonly;
            StepTaskViewInfo.PeerReview.Documents.Items.Add(new ActivityArtifact { FileName = string.Empty });
        }




        private string GetAliases(ObservableCollection<SelectableTeamMember> selectedStepMembers)
        {
            string aliases= selectedStepMembers.Aggregate("", (current, member) => current + (member.Alias + ";"));
            aliases= aliases.TrimEnd(';');
            return aliases;
        }
        private string GetDisplayNames(ObservableCollection<SelectableTeamMember> selectedStepMembers)
        {
            string names = selectedStepMembers.Aggregate("", (current, member) => current + (member.Name + ";"));
            names= names.TrimEnd(';');
            return names;
        }

        public void AssignResourcesToStep(ObservableCollection<SelectableTeamMember> selectedStepMembers)
        {
            StepTaskViewInfo.CurrentStep.StepTeamMembers = selectedStepMembers;
            StepTaskViewInfo.CurrentStep.Resources = GetAliases(selectedStepMembers);
            StepTaskViewInfo.CurrentStep.StepResourceDisplayName = GetDisplayNames(selectedStepMembers);


            foreach (var task in StepTaskViewInfo.CurrentStep.ProjectTasks)
            {
                task.AllTaskTeamMembers = StepTaskViewInfo.CurrentStep.StepTeamMembers;
                task.Resources = GetAliases(StepTaskViewInfo.CurrentStep.StepTeamMembers);
                task.TaskResourceDisplayName = GetDisplayNames(StepTaskViewInfo.CurrentStep.StepTeamMembers);
            }
        }

        public void AssignResourcesToTask(ObservableCollection<SelectableTeamMember> selectedTaskMembers, string taskId)
        {

            var task = StepTaskViewInfo.CurrentStep.ProjectTasks.First(st => st.Id == taskId);
            task.Resources = GetAliases(selectedTaskMembers);
            task.TaskResourceDisplayName = GetDisplayNames(selectedTaskMembers);

        }

        public void AssignTaskTips(string ttid)
        {

            string taskTip = projectWorkflowService.GetTaskTip(ttid);


            foreach (var task in StepTaskViewInfo.CurrentStep.ProjectTasks)
            {
                if (task.TemplateTaskId == ttid)
                    task.TaskTip = taskTip;
            }

        }

        #region peerreview
        public void DownloadDocument(string artifactId, string fileName)
        {
            projectWorkflowService.DownloadActivityArtifact(artifactId, fileName);
        }
        public void UploadDocument(string artifactId,string file)
        {
            projectWorkflowService.UploadActivityArtifact(StageId, artifactId, file);
            var projectDocuments = projectWorkflowService.LoadPeerReviewDocuments(StageId);
            projectDocuments.Items.Add(new ActivityArtifact { FileName = string.Empty });

            StepTaskViewInfo.PeerReview.Documents = projectDocuments;
        }

        private void GetUsers()
        {
            foreach (ProjectPeerReview t in StepTaskViewInfo.PeerReview.Reviews.Items.ToList())
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Id))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Alias))
                    {
                        User current = userService.SearchAlias(t.Alias);

                        if (current == null)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Could not find reviewer " + t.Alias);
                            StepTaskViewInfo.PeerReview.Reviews.Items.Remove(t);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            t.Name = current.Name;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        internal User[] GetSearchingUsersName(string name)
        {
            return userService.Search(name);
        }

        #endregion

        public void UpdateTaskStatus(object selectedValue)
        {
            foreach (var task in StepTaskViewInfo.CurrentStep.ProjectTasks)
            {
                task.Status = selectedValue.ToString();
            }
        }

        public void LoadTasksForCurrentStep()
        {
            StepTaskViewInfo.CurrentStep.ProjectTasks = projectWorkflowService.LoadProjectTasks( StepTaskViewInfo.CurrentStep.Id);

            StepTaskViewInfo.UpdateTaskResources();
        }

        public void SaveCurrentTasksWithStep()
        {
            if (StepTaskViewInfo.CurrentStep != null)
            {
                projectWorkflowService.SaveTasksWithStep(StageId, StepTaskViewInfo.CurrentStep, StepTaskViewInfo.CurrentStep.ProjectTasks);
            }
        }

        public bool SaveData()
        {
            if (StepTaskViewInfo.CurrentStep != null)
            {
                GetUsers();
                return projectWorkflowService.SaveStepTaskViewInfo(StepTaskViewInfo, StageId);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Please post the ViewModel code structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataGridColumn.IsReadOnly property will make all cells in the column either ReadOnly or not ReadOnly. DataGridCell.IsReadOnly property is not assignable too. What you are trying to do is to make a column readonly if some other property is false, else column should be editable. It is better to use a template column and set the control accordingly. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.isreadonly(v=vs.110).aspx)

For example, if I want user to edit CarNumber property value is HasCar property value is true else not, then if I write :

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="CarNumber" Binding="{Binding CarNumber}"  IsReadOnly="{Binding HasCar"/>
```

//

This will still allow all column values to be editable irrespective of HasCar value.

//

If I use Template column and use DataTrigger then I get the desired effect. This wont allow user to type/edit CarNumber if HasCar property is false :

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="CarNumber" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>                            
                          <TextBox x:Name="TxtCarNumber" Text="{Binding CarNumber}" >
                            <TextBox.Style>
                               <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasCar}" Value="False">
                                                                <Setter Property="TextBox.Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                                                <Setter Property="TextBox.Width" Value="100"/>
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasCar}" Value="True">
                                                                <Setter Property="TextBox.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                                <Setter Property="TextBox.Background" Value="Red"/>
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBox.Style>
                          </TextBox>                            
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

In your code do this, as you want your CheckBox to remain visible but not enabled :

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width ="60" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" Header="Selected" >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Grid IsEnabled={Binding StepTaskViewInfo.AreStepsTasksReadonly}>
              <CheckBox  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  
IsChecked="{Binding  IsSelected,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                 IsEnabled="{Binding IsTaskEnabled,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
            </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: @PrasaanthNeelakandan You better know your code and from where StepTaskViewInfo.AreStepsTasksReadonly is coming from. If StepTaskViewInfo.AreStepsTasksReadonly value is false, then entire Grid in DataTemplate will be disabled and hence your combobox too. I will post a working solution showing this.

Comment: @PrasaanthNeelakandan If StepTaskViewInfo.AreStepsTasksReadonly is false, then your combobox in that row will not be accessible as Grid containing it will be disabled.

Comment: @PrasaanthNeelakandan <Grid IsEnabled={Binding StepTaskViewInfo.AreStepsTasksReadonly} in this line I forgot to put closing tag of Grid. Rest is fine, I have checked at my end.

Comment: @PrasaanthNeelakandan I have added closing tag for Grid which was missing earlier, now you can check and update back.

Comment: am sorry ..i figured the missing tag that day itself ..it works :) sorry didnt get back earlier... earlier even with the tag it was nt working due to some other issue.. +15 to u